# Dynamic variable creation in a loop by queryselectorAll

Tags: javascript

with this code I managed to create a child to each of the elements of the Node list via QueryselctorAll but I need to retrieve the tille ((document.queryseletor(....).title) works but not dynamically...) of the parent div dynamically as a variable to enter it in the innerHTML of the child. Do you have an idea ?

```
function onloaddiv() {
  for (const item of document.querySelectorAll('.mat_option')) {
    divp = document.createElement("div");
    var2 = document.querySelector(".mat_option").title;
    divp.innerHTML= "" + var2;
    item.append(divp);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  In what way is the code shown not working as expected?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: A few major points to hit with any question:  1) provide code that reproduces the problem entirely and explain how to reproduce it (A runnable snippet is best because the instructions should be "click Run Code Snippet") 2) Describe the expected results, 3) Describe the actual results, 4) Give a brief explanation of why you think the code you wrote should produce the expected results and not the actual results - this will help people correct any misunderstandings you have.

Comment: `document.querySelector(".mat_option")` gets you the first matching element in the DOM and not the parent of `item`. Use `.closest()` or `.parentNode` or `.parentElement` or what ever gets you the actual parent (without the relevant markup this is just guessing...).

Answer (score 1):

From your description I'm not 100% sure what you'd like to achieve, but maybe this?

```js
function onloaddiv() {
  for (const item of document.querySelectorAll('.mat_option')) {
    divp = document.createElement("div");
    var2 = item.title;
    divp.innerHTML= "" + var2;
    item.append(divp);
  }
}
```

Comment: The subject is resolved, thank you all for your quick answers. Viktor Luft's code worked right away. Good evening :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to query selector once again, you already have item in your loop

```js
function onloaddiv() {
  for (const item of document.querySelectorAll('.mat_option')) {
    divp = document.createElement("div");
    divp.innerHTML = item.title;
    item.append(divp);
  }
}
```

It doesn't work "dynamically", as you say, because *document.querySelector(...)* returns only first element it could find.